# Is there any way to mint an NFT with metadata without passing URI in mint?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I want to create an application that receives a contract address and create a frontend for other users to mint the NFTs from that contract. But I don't have any metadata for that contract, could this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd really be helpful if you could try to be a little more specific on what you're trying to accomplish when asking your question. I'll try to answer your question by providing you with some basic information on minting NFTs in general.

Assuming we make use of the most common standard for making NFTs, the so-called ERC721 standard, you're actually in charge of implementing the mint function. In the most basic implementation, you could even skip the metadata, however that'd leave you with an NFT collection, where an NFT is nothing more than a unique identifier. In short, you'll need to code the implementation of the mint function and choose whether it should make use of metadata or not. You can even choose to make the implementation in a way, where the metadata could be optional. It's all up to you!

I hope that answers your question.